# Why does dojo.xhrGet needs different kinds of url to work on different computers (pc/mac)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, greasemonkey

i'm writing an greasemonkey script for somebody else. he is a moderator and i am not. and the script will help him do some moderating things.

now the script works for me. as far as it can work for me.(as i am not a mod)
but even those things that work for me are not working for him..

i checked his version of greasemonkey plugin and firefox and he is up to date.
only thing that's really different is that i'm on a mac and he is pc, but i wouldn't think that would be any problem.

this is one of the functions that is not working for him. he does gets the first and third GM_log message. but not the second one ("got some(1) ..").

```
kmmh.trackNames = function(){
GM_log("starting to get names from the first "+kmmh.topAmount+" page(s) from leaderboard.");
kmmh.leaderboardlist = [];
for (var p=1; p<=(kmmh.topAmount); p++){
    var page = "http://www.somegamesite.com/leaderboard?page="+ p;  
    var boardHTML = "";
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: page,
        sync: true,
        load: function(response){   
            boardHTML = response;
            GM_log("got some (1) => "+boardHTML.length);
        },
        handleAs: "text"
    });

    GM_log("got some (2) => "+boardHTML.length);

    //create dummy div and place leaderboard html in there
    var dummy = dojo.create('div', {    innerHTML: boardHTML    });
//search through it
    var searchN = dojo.query('.notcurrent', dummy).forEach(function(node,index){
        if(index >= 10){
            kmmh.leaderboardlist.push(node.textContent);    // add names to array
        }
    });
}
GM_log("all names from "+ kmmh.topAmount +" page(s) of leaderboard ==> "+ kmmh.leaderboardlist);
```

does anyone have any idea what could be causing this ??

EDIT: i know i had to write according to what he would see on his mod screen. so i asked him to copy paste source of pages and so on. and besides that, this part of the script is not depending on being a mod or not.

i got everything else working for him. just this function still doesn't on neither of his pc's.

EDIT2 (changed question): OK. so after some more trial and error, i got it to work, but it's still weird.
when i removed the www-part of the url thats being use in the dojo.xhrGet() i got the finally the same error he got. so i had him add www to his and now it works.
the odd thing is he now uses a script with the url containing "www" and i'm using a script with an url without "www"...

so for me: 
`var page = "http://somegamesite.com/leaderboard?page="+ p;`
and for him:
`var page = "http://www.somegamesite.com/leaderboard?page="+ p;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ooops. it seemed that the url of this gamesite is accessible as www.gamesite.com as well as gamesite.com (without the www.part). this caused the problem.

sorry to bother you'all.

i go hide in shame now...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have him try logging into an account that is not a moderator account so that you eliminate one of your variables from your problem space.

It's possible that the DOM of the page is different for a moderator than for a regular user.  If you're making assumptions about the page as a regular user that are not true as a moderator, that could cause problems.

I suspect that to fix it, you may need access to a moderator account so you can more easily replicate the behavior.

Comment: +1. It is so obvious that mods can have different layout, more stuff to pages than regular users. If the site doesn't use selectors thoroughly, there can be issues.

Comment: i knew this so i build to script based on info he gave me. he gave me his login and i tested from his account now. all works for me. but not for him..